# Game dedicated server application crash/delay after some time on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, games, crash, process, sockets

I've been running a game server application which, after some time, crashes with all the people connected to it (packets delay for one/two minutes making most people disconnect although the application stays open, recovering itself for new people connections thereafter).

The server is running on a VPS with one vCore, 2 GB RAM and 100 mbps network bandwidth. I've monitored the resources, and when game server is full, CPU is working at about 60% (load average about 1.7 for 15 minutes), while the RAM always at about 30%. Upload consuming about 15 mbps. Firewall disabled.

It's the Assetto Corsa dedicated server which I'm talking about.

NOFILE ulimit set to a big value.

No GUI installed, just Ubuntu 20.04 server from OVH.

I've changed provider too, the result has been that the server still crashed like the previous one.

Here there are the logs at the moment of crash.

```
2021-05-20 20:42:34,760: PAGE: /cq/kehulistajax.php
2021-05-20 20:42:35,131: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,132: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,331: PAGE: /check.php
2021-05-20 20:42:35,608: PAGE: /api/wallet/redDetail
2021-05-20 20:42:35,632: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,632: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,655: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:35,734: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:35,891: PAGE: /h5/
2021-05-20 20:42:35,939: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,939: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,983: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,983: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:36,094: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:36,175: PAGE: /index.php/Wap/Api/getBanner
2021-05-20 20:42:36,269: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:36,269: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:36,450: PAGE: /index.php/Wap/Api/getSystemNotice
2021-05-20 20:42:36,830: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:37,344: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:37,617: PAGE: /script/public.js
2021-05-20 20:42:37,775: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:38,157: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:38,157: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:38,559: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,130: PAGE: /api/site/getInfo.do
2021-05-20 20:42:40,214: New connection from &{{14664763300}}
2021-05-20 20:42:40,214: SOCKET NO DELAY SET
2021-05-20 20:42:40,215: PAGE: /locale/Goex/zh/common.js
2021-05-20 20:42:40,219: PAGE: /JS/loginstatus.js
2021-05-20 20:42:40,465: PAGE: /base/goexjs
2021-05-20 20:42:40,622: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,834: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,918: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:41,171: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,171: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,178: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,178: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,359: PAGE: /other/codepay/js/codepay_util.js
2021-05-20 20:42:41,429: PAGE: /anquan/qgga.asp
2021-05-20 20:42:41,679: PAGE: /statics/js/API.js
2021-05-20 20:42:41,796: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,797: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,930: PAGE: /common/download.js
2021-05-20 20:42:42,712: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:43,977: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:43,988: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,353: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,857: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,868: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:44,868: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:44,970: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:45,186: PAGE: /config
2021-05-20 20:42:45,376: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:45,376: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:45,822: PAGE: /user/login
2021-05-20 20:42:46,100: PAGE: /zz2/address.php
2021-05-20 20:42:46,722: PAGE: /
2021-05-20 20:42:47,831: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:47,832: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:48,667: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:48,696: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,017: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,191: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:51,192: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:51,438: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,641: PAGE: /style.css
2021-05-20 20:42:51,994: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,994: PAGE: /js/json.js
2021-05-20 20:42:52,096: PAGE: /api/currency/quotation_new
2021-05-20 20:42:52,174: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:52,174: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:52,178: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:52,178: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:52,241: PAGE: /Content/css/wzwstylel.css
2021-05-20 20:42:52,279: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:52,562: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
- - - - - - -  other example of crash logs - - - - - - - -
2021-05-10 14:47:38,480: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-10 14:47:38,657: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:43602: write: connection timed out
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:56621: write: broken pipe
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:63440: write: broken pipe

many many more for 1/2 minutes

EDIT: I've seen also a no route to host error added to connection timeout and broken pipe.
```

I've seen on the code above strange strings like "PAGE: /api/wallet/redDetail".

What does they mean? They don't mean nothing for the game application, seems like an interference with the system.

Strings like this one are not seen during normal game server running.

I think this is a good hint for understanding the issue.

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I'm trying to edit the post from time to time, as I see no one is answering my question. Why is this happening? I don't know what to do more and I don't want to give up.

Answer (score 0):

There are various bots trying to scraper servers every now and then, this is just one of them trying to hit an endpoint on your server expecting to get some valuable data without you knowing, if you have a request tracking setup in place, you can consider blocking that server's IP address so they won't be able to request again.

But that doesn't solve the problem since tomorrow another weird request will come in from another IP. So it's just how the internet world is, just make sure to not give away any credentials or private data in an unprotected endpoint.

Could be safely ignored if it's a personal project or something that doesn't have too much "precious" data.